# How to insert applet into shiny R

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I would like to include applet for visualizing molecular structures using shiny (I'm a beginner in html and shiny) and I have two problems.

First, when I include the html file it generates an error "Error connecting to server: https://chemapps.stolaf ..."

code:

```
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  includeHTML("applet.html"),
  mainPanel()
))
```

where applet.html is:

```
<html>
<body>
Applet
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=acetone&inline">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I press "Open in browser" after running the code, it works fine.
Can it work in shiny without opening in a browser?

Second, and more importantly I need to load the applet from the server:

```
#  ----- ui.R -----
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
))

#  ----- server.R -----
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("applet.html"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})
})
```

However, the applet doesn't work, although it seems that the html file is loaded properly also because the "applet" text appears.

I would appreciate any kind of help